# SQL: Counting amount of duplicate records after group by

Tags: sql

I have a large table containing information about which items (and in what amount) belong to which ordernumber.

Now, this table is special in that it records all changes made in items linked to the ordernumber. Kind of like this:

```
OrderNumber | ItemNumber | ItemAmnt 
125           ITM1         2
125           ITM1         -2
125           ITM1         1
125           ITM2         5
125           ITM2         -5
125           ITM2         3
125           ITM3         1
125           ITM4         2
```

To make the problem even harder it has a seemingly random amount of duplicate records inserted aswell. Making it look like so:

```
OrderNumber | ItemNumber | ItemAmnt   |  Count
125           ITM1         2             5
125           ITM1         -2            4
125           ITM1         1             7
125           ITM2         5             3
125           ITM2         -5            4
125           ITM2         3             2
125           ITM3         1             3
125           ITM4         2             3
```

What I would like to achieve is to get the sum up the ItemAmnt of every ItemNumber IGNORING the amount of duplicates (a.k.a Count column). E.g.: for ITM1 this would be "2 - 2 + 1 = 1", for ITM2 it would be "5 - 5 + 3 = 3".

I hope I'm making myself clear here, i'd be happy to elaborate.

The current SQL-code to achieve the table above:

```
select ordernumber, itemnumber, itemamnt, count(*) From item2order Where ordernumber='125' group by itemnumber, itemamnt
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What RDBMS and version are you using?

Comment: It's an old Foxpro .DBF-file

Comment: @AleixHernandez How do you run **FoxPro** in `windows 7`. I have search a lot over it, but could not found any relevant and reliable answer. Could u please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand, you have done half the job.
Use the query you write as a subquery for a `SUM` query like this:

```
SELECT ordernumber, itemnumber, SUM(itemamnt)
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ordernumber, itemnumber, itemamnt
    FROM item2order
    WHERE ordernumber='125' 
) AS SubQ
GROUP BY ordernumber, itemnumber
```

I have replaced `GROUP BY` with `DISTINCT`, but it is the same result. The readability is better with `DISTINCT` because it is doing exactly what you want, eliminate duplicates before summing.

Comment: Thank you! This is probably the answer in modern applications, but subquerying doesn't seem to work in foxpro (or i can't seem to make it work).

Comment: What error did you get? Try again, I add an alias for the subquery, most DBMS require an alias, I just forgot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT 
   ordernumber, 
   itemnumber, 
   sum(itemamt) AS TotalAmt
FROM 
   item2order
GROUP BY 
   ordernumber, 
   itemnumber
```

If you want for specific record add according `where` clause